# AJAX bold the changes of content for X seconds

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I installed a Wordpress website and i use LeagueManager plugin for soccer categories/rankings/results.
Now, i am trying to convert the results page to livescore page. How? With the following way:

LeagueManager has a shortcode for match day. For example [matches league=1 match_day=8]
To make an autorefreshing page i created 2 pages. The first page (private) contains the above shortcode and the second one (public) contains the div that ajax code auto-refresh!

This is the AJAX Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval( function() {
    $('div#livescores').load('http://www.ismood.com/dinataathlitika.gr/live #live');
}, 5000);
</script>
```

I want to know how i can give a bold format to last changes of results for one refresh period. For example:

**First Refresh:**

`Team A-Team B 0-0`

`Team C-Team D 0-0`

**Second Refresh (after 30sec):**

`Team A-Team B 1-0 (bold here)`

`Team C-Team D 0-0`

**Third Refresh (after 30sec):**

`Team A-Team B 1-0`

`Team C-Team D 0-0`

As i can understand, it s obligated to find how to seperate match per match so i can edit edit the style of each row but i dont know how to do it :(

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend doing a little bit more work on the client-side so that you can store the scores for each game in JavaScript variables, then you could compare the newly retrieved game scores with the ones collected previously, and bold any lines that represent a game score that is different from the last one collected. You would have to build the HTML content on the client side when updating.